# I want to know the details of ticketing agreement options in amadeus create order api

Tags: amadeus

I am using amadeus self service api to book flights. The request body that documentation showed has ticketingAgreement field. I want to know details about the field values and if this field value has some connections with the ticket being issued.
Example:

```
"ticketingAgreement": {
    "option": "DELAY_TO_CANCEL",
    "delay": "6D"
 },
```

Now the option field takes other values like "CONFIRM", "DELAY_TO_QUEUE", "DELAY_TO_CANCEL".
I did not understand what actually these value means and I tried to contact support as well but they are not replying.

Issue I faced is, ticket is being issued automatically after booking. I need to stop ticket being issued so that payment process can be taken before ticket is issued.

Link to documentation: https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/flights/api-doc/flight-create-orders/api-reference

Answer (score 2):

as you would need to work with a consolidator for issuance, you can arrange the time of issuance with the consolidator by inputting the parameters of "DELAY_TO_QUEUE" and "DELAY_TO_CANCEL".

- DELAY_TO_QUEUE: this allows you to queue the reservation for the desired date if the traveller does not make the payment.
- DELAY_TO_CANCEL: if the traveler does not make the payment, the reservation for the desired date will be cancelled.

references:

- [How does payment work](https://amadeus4dev.github.io/developer-guides/faq/#how-does-payment-work-when-i-book-a-flight)
- [How to make the airline consolidator wait before issuing a ticket?](https://amadeus4dev.github.io/developer-guides/faq/#how-to-make-the-airline-consolidator-wait-before-issuing-a-ticket)
- [Flight Booking Engine 101 video tutorial - 4. manage your booking and issuance](https://youtu.be/--oFZEbMcmk?si=4QnSeETcU_nZDFrI)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you have any idea about increasing the flight prices by certain percent than given by amadeus API?